# How to enable akamai cache for images, css, js etc

Tags: javascript, css, image, caching, akamai

I would like to set akamai caching for my website. To set caching for images, HTML/CSS, js files, do I need to create separate domains for images.abc.com, css.abc.com, js.abc.com etc to speedup my website?

Assumption here is that will it be helpful in parallel calling of these resources to increasing pagespeed.

Please guide.

Comment: You don't need different domains. Contact your account rep and they can walk you though this.

Answer (score 0):

you can setup caching for any extension you want. you just have to provide this in caching rules and how long should the content be cached etc. This can be done using akamai property manager.